# Will wubi work in HP Pavilion G6

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, hp-pavilion

Because i want to install xubuntu on HP Pavilion g6 but will the wi-fi work (and bluetooth) and the touchpad. (and black screen). I want to ask you guys before i install Xubuntu

Thank you for every answer

Comment: Hello, welcome to the community, to your question, I would suggest you to search for "HP Pavilion G6" here. Also, if you need these information, we need to know what's your Wifi / Bluetooth / Video card. Last but not least, you could try Xubuntu with LiveUSB, so you will be able to know how it works.

Comment: Best don't use WUBI. It sounds like a nice feature, but it's buggy. You can install Xubuntu by booting from the CD or USB after having checked whether all your hardware works.

Comment: I don't have a wireless card but i have a Wifi Adapter : Realtek RTL8188CE 802,11B/G/N WiFi Adapter. Video Card :512MtATI AMD Radeon HD 6380G (HP). And i don't have a bluetooth card. Today i tried Kubuntu by cd. Every thing worked good except the computer started overheating and there's no WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

Before installing to the hard drive you can test everything on Live CD (or Live usb) session. If it works on Live session most likely it will work after the installation, as well.